# How To Make A Barcode Scanner In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, helper, flutterflow

So this is no easy barcode scanner I want it to recognize which country it is from. can someone explain to me how can I do this??

I made a barcode scanner I only need to know how to get it to recognize the country, all other things are done

I have already tried making a whole list of items that tell which country they come from but it doesn't work heck the app doesn't even launch now

Comment: "*this is no easy barcode scanner*" - so, this is a non-trivial programming challenge, and you've shown no work, only a general set of requirements, and left everything up to the Community - this isn't how Stack Overflow works. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, please post a [mcve] with all relevant details (code, sample input, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GS1_country_codes